# Use presentViewController inside EAGLview or View

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have `EAGLView`, i'm taking the screenshot of eaglview from *glReadPixels*. It's working and saving to photo album, i need to share this to social. So, i used `UIActivityViewController`. When i use this inside `EAGLView`, i'm getting NO visible interface for `presentViewController`.

```
 UIImage *glImage = [self glToUIImage];
        UIImage *screensht = [self createSavableImage:glImage];

        NSArray *activityItems = @[screensht];

        UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
        avc.excludedActivityTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, nil];
        [self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

`presentViewController:animated:completion:` is a method of the UIViewController class, not of an UIView, or its subclasses. `self` in the last line in your code points to your EAGLView instance.

Comment: What should i change?

Comment: You need a UIViewController. Actually, the piece of work you actually implement should be triggered from a UIViewController requesting the UIImage (this can be created by the EAGLView) through an IBAction, and once it obtains the UIImage, launch the UIActivityViewController. You need to separate View work from Controller work, and better not mixed the two. Single Responsibility Principle, as much as you can.